CodeDeploy in AWS gives error of timeout after 60 minutes in INSTALL Event of Development Lifecycle
CodeDeploy in AWS gives error of timeout after 60 minutes in INSTALL Event of Development Lifecycle.
Docker Image size is around 310 MB
some time it is success but most of the time it fails.
I have implemented CI/CD using BitBucket Pipeline and its is success always and after that codedeploy started in AWS and After running for 1 hour it fails.
